# How to use variable in the sed command using PHP to replace line

Tags: php, bash, command-line, sed, environment-variables

I want to find and replace the whole line including adding new text in PHP using sed command in Linux. I tried below, but it does not work for variable but it works when I manually pass.

Example (This is Working):

```
$var = exec("sed -i '/Tom/c Tom Rick' t1.conf");
```

Example (This is not working):

```
$var1 = "Tom";
$var2 = "Rick";

$var = exec("sed -i '/$var1/c $var1 $var2' t1.conf");
```

I tried with double quote, but still no luck. Can someone please help me to resolve this problem.

Comment: Both examples work when I try. And the tag [tag:environment-variables] is out of place - there are no environment variables directly involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should extract variables out of your string so as to make sure the '$' is not treated as a character ?

```
$var = exec("sed -i '/".$var1."/c ".$var1." ".$var2".' t1.conf");
```

Comment: Thanks Julien! solution worked, after some small modification.